# Increasing memory limit for Drush 9 (without changing php.ini file)

Tags: drupal-8, drush

I'm trying to run:

```
drush updb
```

with drush 9.3.0 on my Drupal 8 site and I'm getting error:

```
The command could not be executed successfully (returned: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/myproject/www/staging.myproject.ch/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/CompiledRoute.php on line 163
```

Tried to run drush like:

php -d memory_limit=1024M vendor/bin/drush ev "echo ini_get('memory_limit')"

and I do get 1024M value, but when I run updb like that I still get previouse memory message.

Here:
https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3294

..I saw that drush 9 is running some tasks in sub-processes and that most likely it's the case with updb command, so even drush starts with increased memory limit sub-task get's default one.

How can I increase memory limit for drush 9 without changing php.ini file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And answer to this is:

```
echo "memory_limit = 512M" > drush.ini
PHPRC=./drush.ini php vendor/bin/drush updb
rm drush.ini
```

I guess this drush.ini can be "normal" static file, but since all this is required because of un-matching server settings (lack PHP of memory) maybe it should not be part of the project...